# Updated route mapping to have blogs on index page list newest content on top

Tags: node.js

I have a simple blog application where I wanted the newest content posted on the index page to appear on the top vs. appear on the bottom of the page. My code was originally

```
router.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
   if(req.query.search){
       var noMatch = null;
       const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
       Blog.find({title: regex}, function(err, blogs){
       if(err){
           console.log("ERROR!");
       } else {
           if(blogs.length < 1){
               noMatch = "No blogs match that query, please try again";
           }
          res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
       }
   });
    } else {
   Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
       if(err){
           console.log("ERROR!");
       } else {
          res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch}); 
       }
    });
   }
});
```

I got some input on how to correct the route to make it appear in order of newest content first

```
router.get("/blogs", function (req, res) {
  if (req.query.search) {
    var noMatch = null;
    Blog.find({title: regex}).sort({created: -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
      Blog.find({title: regex}, function (err, blogs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
          if (blogs.length < 1) {
            noMatch = "No blogs match that query, please try again";
          }
          res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
        }
      });
      Blog.find({}).sort({created: -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
        Blog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
          } else {
            res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

However when I run the server and try to get to the page I am getting an error 502 Bad Gateway connection and I am not sure why this would be.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this and got it to work

```
// INDEX ROUTE
router.get("/blogs", function (req, res) {
  var noMatch = null;  
  if (req.query.search) {
    Blog.find({title: regex}).sort({created: -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR!");
      } else {
        if (blogs.length < 1) {
          noMatch = "No blogs match that query, please try again";
        }
        res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
      }
    });
  } else {
    Blog.find({}).sort({created: -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR!");
      } else {
        res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
      }
    });
  }
});
```